# Concatenating multiple pbm files, cmd

Tags: image, image-processing, file-format

So we have, let's say, 10 files, called 01.pbm, 02.pbm, 03.pbm, etc. Using cmd with commands like paste or clip (or of course any you know) how could you merge all 10 of them keeping the corresponding file size? (if each of them is 1kb, the output should be 10kb). Keep in mind I use windows... (ugh, I know)

Comment: So, let's say your 10 files are each 50x50 pixels. What are you hoping to end up with? A 500x50 pixel image? A 50x500 pixel image? A ZIP file? Are your PBM files P1 or P4?

Answer (score 1):

Use ImageMagick v6 to accomplish the task.

To append (merge) left-to-right:

```
convert *.pbm +append lr_out.pbm
```

To append top-to-bottom:

```
convert *.pbm -append tb_out.pbm
```

For more information read the [documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append)

**Update**

As fmw42 pointed out for IM v7 then the syntax should be:

```
magick *.pbm +append lr_out.pbm
magick *.pbm -append tb_out.pbm
```

Comment: The correct syntax for IM 7 is `magick *.pbm +append lr_out.pbm`. Do not add convert after magick for IM 7. Also IM 7 is not as forgiving about syntax and so the input images need to be read before the +append operator. If using IM 6, then the command should be `convert *.pbm +append lr_out.pbm`

Answer (score -1):

So at the end it's just the simple function "type"...